# Adjust input tag's width according to value's font

Tags: css

This seems like a very strange issue to me. I have a text input with no size CSS applied to it. When I change the font the text no longer fits:

```
<input type="text" value="270.50" size="4" maxlength="128">

input {
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JZK4N/

[image]

I cannont change the HTML at all. How can I solve this without setting an explicit width to the input with CSS?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with pure CSS. You don't have to change the HTML though. If you can add few lines of jQuery code, see my answer.

Comment: As you can see from the answers and comments to them, the question may be interpreted so that you just want the entire text to be visible or so that the field width should exactly match the width of the initial value. If you really mean the latter, you should also specify whether this should apply to the field also when changed by the user (so that the width would generally need to change dynamically).

Answer (score -1):

Is it require size for you?
Because right now size is affected.

Can you try to remove that, I tried and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Since your initial value for the control has 5 characters, not 4 (the period counts as a character), use `size="5"` instead of `size="4"`.

There is no guarantee in general that this will result in adequate rendering, since the meaning of the `size` attribute has been vaguely defined (a number of characters does not generally determine a specific width) and inconsistently implemented. But for the Lato font, major browsers implement `size="5"` reasonably for data like 270.50 (the field is a bit too wide, but not much).

The best way to control the width of a text input box so that it is an exact number of characters is to use the `size` attribute together with a monospace font, i.e. a font where all characters have the same width.

Comment: Yes, unless the font is monospace it's extremely difficult to estimate the width. Although, even if it's proportionally spaced, the browsers can still be funny with the width.

Comment: Here's a fiddle incorporating your suggestion (monospace font). `http://jsfiddle.net/JZK4N/4/` As per your comments on my answer, it seems like you don't want to tolerate ANY extra space. If you look closely, the 'space` on the right is greater than on the left.

Comment: @JeevanJose, you are just acting childishly. Whatever you think of my comments on your answer (which does not address the question asked), you should not jump into commenting on my answer just to defend yours.

Comment: I need to comment because you don't seem to understand what is being asked here. The question says 'Input's text doesn't fit when font is changed'. My answer addresses this precisely.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little complicated. AFAIK, you can't do this without explicitly defining a width. Even then, the width depends on the font you use. The solution I came up with required creating a `span` element with the text, measuring the width and then using that width on the `input` tag. This requires the use of **`javascript/jquery`**, if you would be willing to use that.

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){                    
        var text = $(this).val();
        var fontF = $(this).css("font-family");
        $("body").append("<span id='temp'>" + text + "</span>");
        $("#temp").css("font-family", fontF);
        var mWidth = $("#temp").width();
        $(this).css("width", mWidth);
        $("#temp").remove();
    });
});
```

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9FSs/)

**Update**: If you are worried about the concerns raised by Jukka, see these two fiddles

[**FIDDLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9FSs/1/)

[**FIDDLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9FSs/2/)

Comment: The question does not request for *exact* width on the element but a *sufficient* width. The code in the answer is an attempt at exact width, but it fails, because the default font size in an `input` element is smaller than in a `span` element, so the width is too large.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thank you for your comment. I don't believe it's too large. Plus the question asks for a way to accommodate the text without it overflowing the input field and this answer provides a way for that. If you still think that it's 'too large', I believe if you also center align the text and provide an explicit padding on the input tag, it would fix that. Something like this: `http://jsfiddle.net/e9FSs/1/`

Comment: If you look at the rendering of your jsfiddle on any normal browser, you can see that there empty space on the right of the last character, corresponding to about the width of one character. It is apparently caused by the font size difference that I mentioned.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Did you even look at the fiddle I provided in my COMMENT? There is no space there. Here's another fiddle with no padding `http://jsfiddle.net/e9FSs/2/`

Comment: Centering the content does not change the fact that the box is wider than needed for the text in it. If you want to provide code that sets the width to the exact width needed (which was not requested for), you need to take into account the font size difference.

Comment: The second fiddle I provided has the `EXACT` width as the content.